# Camera view white and useless

Tags: camera

I did try looking through other answers but couldn't find one the same as my problem. So far I have tried deleting and adding 2 new cameras and even tested the 'camera view' without a camera and still got the same result.

Zooming out achieves nothing at all but zooming in does seem to show something

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You accidentally set your cube as the camera object (shortcut Ctrl+Numpad0). To undo it, select your camera in the outliner (expand your collection), then with  the mouse cursor back in the 3D viewport, press Ctrl+Numpad0 again. This often happens because people are trying to snap to the camera (Ctrl+Alt+Numpad0), but the "Alt" fails to engage properly.